# Keyboard displayed in wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a tab bar application in which one of the tabs is fixed in landscape orientation and the remaining tabs are fixed in portrait orientation. If the tab with landscape orientation is opened first followed by a tab with portrait orientation, the keyboard appears with the wrong orientation in the portrait tab and it is partially clipped. This happens only in iOS 8. In iOS 7 the orientation looks good. I have attached screenshots of how they appear in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no screenshots.

Comment: Sorry forgot, they are available now

Answer (score 0):

By dismissing keyboard while change orientation you can solve this issue. To dismiss keyboard you can use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     _currentOrientation = 1;
}
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
        [self orientationChanged];

}
-(void)orientationChanged{
    if ((self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) && (_currentOrientation==1 || _currentOrientation==3)) {
        _currentOrientation=2;
        [self.view endEditing:YES]
    }
    else{
        if ((self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) && (_currentOrientation==1 || _currentOrientation==2)) {
            _currentOrientation=3;
            [self.view endEditing:YES]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the keyboard is not at all open. If I open it for the first time, this happens

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit. The tab which is fixed to landscape orientation has no textfield. The tab which is fixed to portrait orientation has a web form which has text fields for email and password. When the landscape tab is first visited followed by the portrait tab, and the text field in the portrait tab gains focus, the keyboard is displayed in the wrong orientation and gets cut partially. This happens only in iOS 8 though. I tested in iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.4 simulators.